# How to split a line by space to get the strings not split to each characters?

Tags: python, split

this is part of my data:

```
object 1 class gridpositions counts 47 47 48

origin -39.224729 -29.593729 -18.740000
```

what I want is to split the first line by space to get: 'object', '1', 'class'...
but the problem is I tried

```
line.split()
re.split()

for line in open(input_file, "r").readlines()[0]:
    line_split=line.strip().split()
```

it split the first line to each alphabet:

```
['o']
['b']
['j']
['e']
['c']
['t']
['', '']
```

what I want to get is the number on the first line, 47,47,48. how can I split the first line by space, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating character by character through the first line. Try this instead:

```
with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    line_split = next(f).split()
```

You should use `with` to free any resources used by the file. `next(f)` returns the first line.

Comment: super! it works! ['object', '1', 'class', 'gridpositions', 'counts', '47', '47', '48'] This is the first time I used split() and it split to each character. Why this file with split() it doesn't work?

Comment: No, your error was before that. You were iterating a string, not a list of strings. Also, if this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (click on the grey checkmark on the left). Therefore, others will know that the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I made a mistake. They are different:

```
#1. select the first line and 'for loop'is iterating each string in the first line
for line in open(input_file, "r").readlines()[0]:
#2. select the first line
for line in open(input_file, "r").readlines()[0:1]:
```

The second one also works.